# Erro ao executar arquivo .exe gerado pelo Code::Blocks

Tags: c, dll

Na pasta `bin/debug` do projeto Code::Blocks, ele avisa esse erro. como posso corrigir? Baixei a DLL e mandei pro `system32`, mas persiste o erro.
[image: SS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O MinGW, o compilador que o Code::Blocks está usando, exige esta DLL nas aplicações que ele gera em certas circunstâncias para poder tratar as exceções recebidas. Ela deve acompanhar o executável sempre, ou pelo menos estar em local que possa ser localizada automaticamente pelo sistema operacional. A solução é mantê-la junto da aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei outra forma.
Tenho dois computadores, os executáveis gerados em um necessitavam da .dll e os gerados no outro não....
Comparei os dois programas instalados (Settings > Compiler... > Tollchain Executables > Compiler's installation directory), o do notebook apontava para o MinGW 4.8.1 necessitando da libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll junto do .exe gerado para executar, porém o do desktop aponta para o MinGW 4.9.2, onde esse .exe já é gerado sem necessidade de adicionar a .dll.
Portanto, apenas alterei o caminho do compilador do notebook para a versão mais nova e meu problema se foi! Espero ter ajudado!

[image: Caminho do compilador antigo (no meu caso)]
[image: Caminho do compilador que resolveu meu caso]